# width of textarea in MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I use IDE to generate a view and controller from model automatically in MVC, however, when I try to change the size of textAreafor, I found the width has limitation , I cant make it more widely...  here is my code, hope for some help

```
 @model VeganCommunityApplication.Models.Article

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Article</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

      .
      .
      .

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content,20,70,new {@style="width:400px;height:400px" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

[image: Here is screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Change your textarea to this:

`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content,20,70,new { @class = "col-md-12" })`

This will make it 100% as wide as it's parent element.

For reference: [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Answer (score 1):

You can change it like this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @class = "whatever-class",     @cols = 40, @rows = 40 })

.whatever-class{
    width:400px;
    height:400px
}
```

Comment: PLease check this solution